# PHP Как подключиться БД MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Что я делаю не так... не получается отправить запрос к базе данных. Mysql

```
<?php
echo ( phpversion());
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "q1w2e3r4@_0q1@", "test") or die("Не могу соединиться");;
mysqli_select_db("test");
if (!$link) {
    echo "Ошибка: Невозможно установить соединение с MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Код ошибки errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Текст ошибки error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}


echo "Соединение с MySQL установлено!" . PHP_EOL;
echo "Информация о сервере: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

mysqli_real_query("CREATE TABLE mytable(test_name VARCHAR(30))")or die("Ошибка запроса");;

/* Для определения версии библиотеки клиента
   нет необходимсоти в создании подключения */

printf("Версия клиента: %s\n", mysqli_get_client_info());
/* вывести версию сервера */
printf("Server version: %s\n", mysqli_get_server_info($link));

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: что пишет ошибка которую вы не приводите? а вы знали что синтаксис выбора БД такой `bool mysqli_select_db ( mysqli $link , string $dbname )` ???  А вы  знали что синтаксис запроса такой: `bool mysqli_real_query ( mysqli $link , string $query )` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Что я делаю не так...

К сожалению - практически всё. Судя по всему, вы выбрали процедурный способ обращения с помощью `mysqli`, но не указываете идентификатор соединения ни для `mysqli_select_db()`, ни для `mysqli_real_query()`.

Неправильно:

```
mysqli_select_db("test");
```

Правильно:

```
mysqli_select_db($link, "test");
```

С `mysqli_real_query()` та же история.

Документация по [mysqli_select_db()](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.select-db.php) и [mysqli_real_query()](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-query.php).